# Missing Link between Call Tree and Bottom-up in Chrome Devtools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, profiling

When using the Performance profiler in Chrome's Devtools, the Bottom-up view is a convenient way to find functions of my code that consume most of the time. Then of course it would be nice to learn how the time is spent, so I want to see the Call Tree of that function, but I cannot find a link between these two views. What I have to do instead is to manually walk through the Call Tree from the root node until I find my function, which can be quite a lot of work.

Here is an example. I identified C.o.onmessage as a function where a big chunk of the overall time is spent.

[image]

Now I want to find that function in the Call Tree view.

[image]

Is there an easy way to find the function?

Comment: Could you simply expand the entry in the Bottom-up view, which shows the list of callers too?

Comment: @wOxxOm That would be the list of callers (the paths to the root), what I am looking for is the tree of callees (the tree below).

Comment: Well, post a feature request on https://crbug.com.

Comment: @wOxxOm Will do unless someone comes up with an idea here. That is why I asked the question.

Comment: @Waruyama I am also facing same issue. :(

Comment: @Waruyama Did you file it on crbug.com? if yes can you provide a link?

Comment: @Jens Sorry, I must have forgotten about that.